# In what case checkAndPut is useful when row to be checked is different from the row of the Put?

Tags: hbase

Here's the [checkAndPut API](https://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html#checkAndPut-byte:A-byte:A-byte:A-byte:A-org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put-).

`public boolean checkAndPut(byte[] row, byte[] family, byte[] qualifier, byte[] value, Put put)`

If my understanding is correct, the `row` parameter can be different from the row of `put`. But why is this useful? I think `checkAndPut` is just like `CompareAndSwap(CAS)` operation found in hardware architecture. `CAS` is comparing and setting a single variable. But `checkAndPut` seems supporting operations on different rows. Is this helpful? Or we need to guarantee `row` is actually the same as the row of `put`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

checkAndPut() is an HBase variant of CAS, its deprecated now, checkAndMutate should be used instead.
As specified in the javadoc, the API atomically checks if a row/family/qualifier value matches the expected value. If it does, it adds the put. If the passed value is null, the check is for the lack of column (ie: non-existance).

Lets take an example table 't1' with column family 'cf1' and understand the behavior in following scenarios -

**Create a row to be inserted**

```
val put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("r1"))
put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cf1"), Bytes.toBytes("q1"), Bytes.toBytes("v1"))
```

**Case 1** - Neither of row, column family or column exist in table

**Result** - A new record is inserted, res = true

```
var res = table.checkAndPut(Bytes.toBytes("r1"), Bytes.toBytes("cf1"), Bytes.toBytes("q1"), null, put)
```

**Case 2** - Re-insert the same record inserted in Case 1

**Result** - No upsert happens as the column already exists, res = false

```
res = table.checkAndPut(Bytes.toBytes("r1"), Bytes.toBytes("cf1"), Bytes.toBytes("q1"), null, put)
```

**Case 3** - Add a new row key r2 with cf1:q1, while Put is still set to rowkey = r1.

**Result** - No upsert happens, we get an exception - "Action's getRow must match the passed row", this implies row key set in checkAndPut is expected to be same as in Put and this API is checking for existence of row, column family and column qualifier in order and against values specified in Put

```
res = table.checkAndPut(Bytes.toBytes("r2"), Bytes.toBytes("cf1"), Bytes.toBytes("q1"), null, put)
```

**Case 4** - Add a new column family cf2 to row key r1 and column q1, while Put is still set to rowkey = r1, column family cf1.

**Result** - No upsert happens, we get an exception - "Column family cf2 does not exist in region t1,,1524474825488.a1f7efa76e78f38d64f95b63222cbfa8. in table 't1'....."

```
res = table.checkAndPut(Bytes.toBytes("r1"), Bytes.toBytes("cf2"), Bytes.toBytes("q1"), null, put)
```

**Case 5** - Instead  of checking for q1 we are checking for existence of q2 in checkAndPut()

**Result** - Here the API will check for whether column q2 exist or not which in our case does not, therefore same column q1 will get updated, as Put is still set to value v1, only timestamp/version of q1 will change, res = true

```
res = table.checkAndPut(Bytes.toBytes("r1"), Bytes.toBytes("cf1"), Bytes.toBytes("q2"), null, put)
```

**Case 6** - In all previous examples, 4th parameter was set to null, here we have specified actual value

**Result** - checkAndPut compares value specified for q1 against Put, since it compares to be equal the insert happens, res = true

```
res = table.checkAndPut(Bytes.toBytes("r1"), Bytes.toBytes("cf1"), Bytes.toBytes("q1"), Bytes.toBytes("v1"), put)
```

Case 3 and 4 answers last part of your question.

From usability perspective I think this API can be useful in scenarios where lot of concurrent updates on same row/column may happen, to avoid any conflicts and stale data, we read validate and then write, like OCC -
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control#OCC_phases

To perform upserts on multiple rows/columns checkAndMutate should be used. [Check - [What is the difference between Hbase checkAndPut and checkAndMutate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40738516/what-is-the-difference-between-hbase-checkandput-and-checkandmutate) ]

Hope this helps.